# convert swf to video in Flash Pro CS5.5

Tags: flash-cs5.5

I have searched the web and here for answers but so far, the links are dead, the how-tos no longer work for the version I have, or there are no answers.

I have a swf animation with full sound and scripting that I'd like to convert into a video or an flv. For some reason, the site I post on screws with my timeline somehow (the timing is off, sounds no longer match up properly with the text) so I thought a video would work better.

I tried using **File>Export>Export to movie** to resolve this. I tried to export to an AVI. When it's scaled down to 300x400 it works just fine (though it looks like total crap). However when I export at the full size, using full colors no compression, I get this.

I'm not sure what to do with it. It's slanted with lines through it and grayscale. VLC player is the only thing that will run it too. WMP dies with errors, saying it's an invalid or corrupt format. Funny thing is, the thumbnail for the video is exactly what it should look like.

I'm not sure what to do with it. Converting it to an .flv is just fine. I have a video converter for that. I just can't get it to convert to flv or even a movie type properly.

Why is it doing this to my video? Is there something better to use to convert? Is there a good one that won't plaster a giant watermark over it?

[image being totally screwed up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4e01.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flabaco** is an online **SWF to video** converter. To answer your questions: It's free, doesn't impose banners or watermarks.

> I have a swf animation with full sound and scripting that I'd like to
>   convert into a video or an flv.

Flabaco converts scripted content.  It preserves the frame rate (fps) & color. It's capable of generating professional quality HD content.

It doesn't convert sound. Nonetheless the converted quality is good and you might be able to get by using another video tool to add sound to the converted video.

You can use the online converter app here: [www.Flash-Banner-Converter.com](http://www.flash-banner-converter.com)

PS: There are some older posts on StackOverflow related to your question.  Just search SWF to video / Flabaco.

Kayo,

FLABACO (`FLA`sh`BA`nner`CO`nverter)